# Make Toast for display the name of downloaded files

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, ftp, download

i have an FTP connection which is working fine , i can download my files using a fragment which call > an asynctaskt which call > the FTP server

```
public static void downloadDirectory(FTPClient ftpClient, String parentDir,
            String currentDir, String saveDir) throws IOException {
        String dirToList = parentDir;
        if (!currentDir.equals("")) {
            dirToList += "/" + currentDir;
        }

        FTPFile[] subFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(dirToList);

        if (subFiles != null && subFiles.length > 0) {
            for (FTPFile aFile : subFiles) {
                String currentFileName = aFile.getName();
                if (currentFileName.equals(".") || currentFileName.equals("..")) {
                    // skip parent directory and the directory itself
                    continue;
                }
                String filePath = parentDir + "/" + currentDir + "/"
                        + currentFileName;
                if (currentDir.equals("")) {
                    filePath = parentDir + "/" + currentFileName;
                }

                String newDirPath = saveDir + parentDir + File.separator
                        + currentDir + File.separator + currentFileName;
                if (currentDir.equals("")) {
                    newDirPath = saveDir + parentDir + File.separator
                            + currentFileName;
                }

                if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                    // create the directory in saveDir
                    File newDir = new File(newDirPath);
                    boolean created = newDir.mkdirs();
                    if (created) {
                        System.out.println("CREATED the directory: "
                                + newDirPath);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("COULD NOT create the directory: "
                                + newDirPath);
                    }

                    // download the sub directory
                    downloadDirectory(ftpClient, dirToList, currentFileName,
                            saveDir);
                } else {
                    // download the file
                    boolean success = downloadSingleFile(ftpClient, filePath,
                            newDirPath);
                    if (success) {
                        System.out.println("DOWNLOADED the file: " + filePath);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("COULD NOT download the file: "
                                + filePath);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                Log.v("LogoutInformation", "Logout from FTP");
                ftpClient.logout();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("LogoutInformation", "Logout Fail");
            }
            try {
                Log.v("DisconnectInformation", "Disconnect from FTP");
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("DisconnectInformation", "Disconnect Fail");
            }

        }
```

Here my function from FTPserver.

```
System.out.println("DOWNLOADED the file: " + filePath);
```

And this is what I want to show on my fragment , i want to make a toast which display the file which is actually in download.
But it's background processing , so i can't display information on my fragment , so i don't know how i can do it.

Comment: You just need a reference to a context to show a Toast, where is this snippet of code located? in a service?

Comment: How about getActivity(). Sample: Toast.makeText(getActivity(),TEXT_HERE, DURATION);

Comment: Ftp server contain my download function and connection , and my asynctask contain the link to this functions. And i call my asynctask on a fragment.@user1281750  I can't getActivity , because i'm using a service @KaHeL

Comment: you can use interface to notify service about filename, from service you broadcast an message whose receiver is defined in activity and from there display a toast

Comment: I agree with the interface as well in case you can't use getActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to do this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Your text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As from tags, you are using AsyncTask. Modify it's constructor to accept a reference to `context`.

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<..> {
    private Context mContext;
    public MyAsyncTask(Context c){
        this.mContext = c;
    }
...
```

When your task is running in `doInBackground`, you should `publishProgress(String)`:

```
doInBackground(String.. params){
    for(something){
        ...
        publishProgress(fileName);
    }
}

publishProgress(String fName){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, name, Toast.Length_long).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "File Downloaded:"+currentFileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the downloadDirectory in the doInBackground event of the AsyncTask class?

If so, you can make Toast message like so:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"DOWNLOADED the file: "+filePath,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Where you make filePath global variable.

Something like that.  Hope it helps..